# Trying to get an AJAX style .load() element to bind with .on() but it's not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, bind

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#nav a, #residential a, #commercial a, #industrial a").not("#nav-services, #quote").on("click", function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    link = link.slice(1);
    $("#main-content").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#main-content").load('index.php?jQueryLoad=true&url=' + link, function() {
            flexsliderload();
            $("#search-term").keyup(areasearch);
            $("#carousel").show();
            $("#search").show();
        });
        $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
    });
    return false;
});
```

The data is being dynamically loaded into a `<div>` called `#main-content` on the page.  Everything is working except for the links inside the newly loaded part.  They are making a standard HTTP request and reloading the page when clicked.  I thought using `.on()` binded them and all future events. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Ok this actually works, but is there anyway to condense down the code into one event?

```
$("#nav").not("#nav-services, #quote").on("click", "a", function() {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        link = link.slice(1);
        $("#main-content").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $("#main-content").load('index.php?jQueryLoad=true&url=' + link, function() {
                flexsliderload();
                $("#search-term").keyup(areasearch);
                $("#carousel").show();
                $("#search").show();
            });
            $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#main-content").on("click", "#residential a, #commercial a, #industrial a", function() {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        link = link.slice(1);
        $("#main-content").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $("#main-content").load('index.php?jQueryLoad=true&url=' + link, function() {
                flexsliderload();
                $("#search-term").keyup(areasearch);
                $("#carousel").show();
                $("#search").show();
            });
            $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the event to the container `#main-content` that exists in DOM any time, rather than binding the event directly to the anchor tags.  You can use the overload of `.on()` syntax that takes the selector to which the event has to be delegated.

So change

```
 $("#nav a, #residential a, #commercial a, #industrial a").not("#nav-services, #quote").on("click", function() {
```

to

```
  $("#main-content").on("click", "#nav a, #residential a, #commercial a, #industrial a", function() {
```

#### JS Snippet

```
  $("#main-content").on("click", "#nav a, #residential a, #commercial a, #industrial a", function() {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        link = link.slice(1);
        $("#main-content").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $("#main-content").load('index.php?jQueryLoad=true&url=' + link, function() {
                flexsliderload();
                $("#search-term").keyup(areasearch);
                $("#carousel").show();
                $("#search").show();
            });
            $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: In addition to links in the `#main-content` I also have a menu bar with parent container called `#nav` with links that do work correctly with the AJAX load. How would I include them as well?

Comment: Your html structure is unclear. i though they are inside main-content. Can you show your html structure too.

Comment: @Phillip yes you can attach it to the `document` instead the selectors i.e $(document).on('click', 'all your selectors here' or have a function which does the activities and call that from both the handlers